# mouse events on multiple polygons in java swing

Tags: java, events, swing, awt, awtutilities

i am trying to write a code for my task.
my task is, i have draw may polygons on a single panel by giving coordinate values. and aplly mouse moved event to those polygons.

my problem is i can draw all polygons but don't know how to apply mousemoved event to all tha polygons.(i.e when i move my mouse to particular polygon the background color of that particual polygon should change, and when i exit it should go back to normal stage).

i can do all this manually for one or two polygons. but in my scenario i'll have so many polygons. i can't write individually for each.

so please help me regarding this issue.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon) show how to solve the problem for one `Polygon`. Note that `mouseMoved()` merely records the current mouse `Point`. In response to `repaint()`, `paintComponent()` makes a check using `contains()`. For multiple polygons, you would simply iterate over a `List<Polygon>`, checking each in turn.